# paging does not work in kendo grid on the first load shows all

Tags: kendo-ui

first load of my kendo grid takes time if the data is more than 1500 rows,i think if i show 100 rows in every page then will take less time,the problem is even thought i set the pages like following it still shows all ,on the first load

```
 dataSource: dataForGrid,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                pageSize: 100,


                // pageSize: 10,
                //serverPaging: true,
                height: 550,
                //  groupable: true,

                sortable: true,
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },

                pageable: {
                    alwaysVisible: true,
                    pageSizes: [10, 20, 40, "all"],
                    numeric: false,
                    message: {
                        empty: 'No Data',
                        allPages: 'All'
                    }
                },
```

also lazy loading does not work,and its really irritating ,as you see i set the page size from 10 to all,means it should start from 10 when the grid is loaded,but it shows all ,here is my controller,

```
 var unfilteredData = (from t in dtUnfilteredData.AsEnumerable()
                            select new EventsViewModel
                            {
                                Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(t["m_time_stamp"]),
                                Description = Convert.ToString(t["m_event_log_description"]),
                                WindSpeed = (float)t["m_wind_speed"],
                                RPM = (float)t["m_rpm"],
                                Power = (float)t["m_power"],
                                EventName = Convert.ToString(t["m_event_type_description"]),
                                User = Convert.ToString(t["m_user_description"]),
                                EventNumber = int.Parse(t["m_event_number"].ToString()),
                                EventTypeId = int.Parse(t["m_event_type_id"].ToString()),
                               // mGid = Convert.ToString(t["m_event_number"]),
                                descFormltSelect = Convert.ToString(t["m_description"])
                            }).ToList() ;

                var Data = new { Data = unfilteredData,isMbox = mbox.isReplicatingMbox };             
                return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: And your server respects the settings of the current page, page size and so on? You have to implement the paging on the server yourself.

Comment: @CarstenFranke how?

Comment: You have to filter, order and limit the result set. LINQ would be an option to do so. For example: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/custom-binding

Comment: @im passing the result via json result,should i do the paging there?

Comment: Guess so, yes. Without code it is hard to tell.

Comment: updated my code, @CarstenFranke

Comment: You have to run the filters, ordering and so on on your `dtUnfilteredData`. So only the relevant data items will be selected and put into the result list. See step 3 in my previous link on how to do it with ordering.

Answer (score 0):

you should resize the grid in the first load, so add this event handler to grid:

```
.Events(e => e.DataBound(@<text>
    function(e) 
    {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.pager.resize();            
    }
</text>))
```